# Откорректировать регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо напишить регулярное выражение, которое найдёт все переменные, записанные в стиле lowerCamelCase
Вот мой код:

```py
import re 
s=input()
po = re.findall(r'(?<=[^\.]\s)[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9][^\W_]+(?=\b)',s)
print(po)
```

Он почему-то не все находит.
Задаю `variableWithNumbers3134 anotherOne1 another1`
Находит только `['anotherOne1', 'another1']`, а почему не находит еще `variableWithNumbers3134`.

Comment: Ну у вас в начале строки должен быть whitespace символ `(?<=[^.]\s)`, поэтому и не находит. Непонятно, как с помощью регулярки вы хотите определить отличие "variableWith" от "variablewith", ведь второе уже не lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Ваша регулярка требует ровно **одну** цифру.

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы моя регулярка работала?

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=(?<!\.)\s))[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9][^\W_]+\b',s)`

Comment: Нашел сам еще такое простое решение    r"\b[a-z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*\b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам еще такое простое решение r"\b[a-z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*\b"

Comment: Для такого выражения `+` не нужен, да и `\b`, если использовать через `re.findall`. Но в любом случае это не защитит от нахождения "vAriablEwithnum3bers3", который не является lowerCamelCase.